# XCode & Interface Builder not in sync anymore

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, asynchronous

it seems to me that ever since a recent upgrade to the latest XCode, some behavior changed.

What Used to Be: 
Whenever I did a "Build and Run", XCode would ask me to save changes to the opened and changed documents in Interface Builder that belong to that project.

Now:
No questions asked, open IB docs are not saved, and the new build is run without the changes in IB.

In IB, the status light at the bottom of the XIB window is green, indicating at least a sync in the other direction.

I guess this is all a simple preference setting, but you all know that preferences in XCode are as comprehensible as Microsoft Word's.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be a lot of people experiencing this, check out this thread ...
[saving-interface-builder-changes-when-building-in-xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556096/saving-interface-builder-changes-when-building-in-xcode)

gary

PS: I am also having this issue since upgrading to 3.2